# How can I connect GPIO pins to RetroPie?

Tags: gpio, retropie, pi-zero-w

I am wanting to connect 12 buttons to RetroPie via the GPIO pins.  The way I understand it, if I enable the pins that the buttons are connected to, I should then be able to map those in RetroPie.

Here are the GPIO pins I want to use:

- GPIO #4
- GPIO #5
- GPIO #6
- GPIO #13
- GPIO #26
- GPIO #20
- GPIO #16
- GPIO #12
- GPIO #17
- GPIO #27
- GPIO #22
- GPIO #23

Is there some script that can be ran that would easily allow me to enable these as buttons in RetroPie?